# Drop down value reset to first value after retrieve

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, internet-explorer, tld

```
<c:set var="modelYear">
<%=((org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm) request.getAttribute("org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BEAN")).getMap().get("modelYear")%>
</c:set>
```

After choose a value in drop down then submit, it will reset to the first value in IE11 alone. In IE8 it is working fine. I am trying to take the selected value from request, but it is not given proper value in IE11.

Comment: IE11 has a bug or a different behaviour, where it caches the chunks html pages. You can disable it by setting response headers in your java controller. For example, `response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");`.   related link- [https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/800257/ie11-clear-browser-cache-in-developer-tools-does-not-clear-the-browser-cache](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/800257/ie11-clear-browser-cache-in-developer-tools-does-not-clear-the-browser-cache)

Comment: IE11 have different behavior, whatever value we choose in the drop down it will reset to the top one. The same code works in IE8 with the selected values of drop down.